# Allow Copy Texts with RenderHTML in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-render-html

I have a problem copying when pressing and highlighting texts in my react native app.
I wanted to achieve something like this picture

[image]

**CODE**

```
import Clipboard from "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard";
import RenderHtml, {
  HTMLContentModel,
  HTMLElementModel,
} from 'react-native-render-html'

const copyToClipboard = (link) => {
  Clipboard.setString(link);
  Toast.show({
    type: "info",
    position: "bottom",
    text1: "Copied to clipboard",
    text2: "",
    visibilityTime: 3000,
    autoHide: true,
    topOffset: 30,
    bottomOffset: 40,
    onShow: () => {},
    onHide: () => {},
    onPress: () => {},
  });
};

const renderEmailBody = (emailItem) => {
  const regex = new RegExp("On .+ wrote:", "g");
  if (regex.test(emailItem.body)) {
    const editBody = emailItem.body.replace(/On .+ wrote:/g, (str) => {
      return str + "<p><extend-button>&#8226&#8226&#8226</extend-button></p>";
    });
    const editBodySplit = editBody.split(
      "<p><extend-button>&#8226&#8226&#8226</extend-button></p>"
    );
    const header =
      editBodySplit[0] +
      "<p><extend-button>&#8226&#8226&#8226</extend-button></p>";

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          Gutters.smallTMargin,
          Gutters.largeHPadding,
          { paddingBottom: wp(1) },
        ]}
        onPress={() => {
          Clipboard.setString(emailItem?.body);
        }}
      >
        {emailItem?.body ? (
          <>
            {!!editBodySplit[0] && (
              <RenderHtml
                contentWidth={width}
                source={{
                  html: header,
                }}
                enableCSSInlineProcessing={false}
                enableExperimentalBRCollapsing={true}
                enableExperimentalGhostLinesPrevention={true}
                enableExperimentalMarginCollapsing={true}
                customHTMLElementModels={customHTMLElementModels}
                renderersProps={{
                  a: {
                    onPress: (event, href) => {
                      navigate("WebView", href);
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
            )}
            {showBodyMess && !!editBodySplit[1] && (
              <RenderHtml
                contentWidth={width}
                source={{
                  html: editBodySplit[1],
                }}
                enableCSSInlineProcessing={false}
                enableExperimentalBRCollapsing={true}
                enableExperimentalGhostLinesPrevention={true}
                enableExperimentalMarginCollapsing={true}
                customHTMLElementModels={customHTMLElementModels}
                renderersProps={{
                  a: {
                    onPress: (event, href) => {
                      // console.log(href)
                      navigate("WebView", href);
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
            )}
          </>
        ) : null}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[
        Gutters.smallTMargin,
        Gutters.largeHPadding,
        { paddingBottom: wp(1) },
      ]}
      onPress={() => {
        Clipboard.setString(emailItem?.body);
      }}
    >
      {emailItem?.body ? (
        <RenderHtml
          contentWidth={width}
          source={{
            html: emailItem?.body,
          }}
          enableCSSInlineProcessing={false}
          enableExperimentalBRCollapsing={true}
          enableExperimentalGhostLinesPrevention={true}
          enableExperimentalMarginCollapsing={true}
          customHTMLElementModels={customHTMLElementModels}
          renderersProps={{
            a: {
              onPress: (event, href) => {
                // console.log(href)
                navigate("WebView", href);
              },
            },
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: you want to achieve this in Text Tag or webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this feature with `Text` tag of react native then use `selectable` prop: [Check](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#selectable)

Edit: If you want to use it with RenderHTML the add this line in props

```
defaultTextProps={{selectable:true}}
```

Example:

```js
<RenderHtml
  contentWidth={width}
  source={source}
  defaultTextProps={{selectable:true}}
/>
```

Comment: Can this work on my code? RenderHtml?

Comment: no it won't work with RenderHtml. Which library are you using to render HTML?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html

Comment: check edit for render html

Comment: yes i have tried it in expo snack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248294/discussion-between-bhavya-koshiya-and-joseph).

Comment: Can you give a link in expo?

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@bkweapplinse/30a28f

Comment: Thank you :)))) You can't test it on emulator, right?

Comment: You can, just long press on mouse

Comment: @BhavyaKoshiya do u know how to copy the text programmatically without highlighting the text manually?

Comment: @AnnieTan Try using this library 
https://github.com/react-native-clipboard/clipboard#readme

Comment: @BhavyaKoshiya yes im using that, but i need to copy the formatted text instead of raw html.